# How to delete old avatar first then upload new avatar?

Tags: laravel

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
    public function uploadAvatar(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'image|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1500|dimensions:max_width=800,max_height=800'
        ] , [
            'image.image' => 'Must be an :attribute!',
            'image.max' => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.',
            'image.mimes' => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
            'image.dimensions' => 'The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.',
        ]);

        if (auth()->user()->avatar) {
            Storage::delete(public_path('user-images/' . auth()->user()->avatar));
        }

        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->image->storeAs('user-images', $filename, 'public');
            auth()->user()->update(['avatar' => $filename]);
            return redirect()->back()->with('successUploadImg', 'Profile picture updated successfully!');
        }
    }
```

Thanks for helping!

Note: I use Storage:Link . I was thinking i wrong with the path

Comment: That seems good, but I guess it's better to delete the prev avatar if request has image, otherwise your avatar would be missing.

Comment: yes this is the correct logic but a good programmer wont create what has been already created. I suggest using https://laravel-mediable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for your media management.

Answer (score 1):

Your deletion should also be inside the condition where you're checking if there's any image being uploaded. Right now, even if you don't upload an avatar it'll delete the old one.

Code:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) { 
   Storage::delete(public_path('user-images/' . auth()->user()->avatar));
   // Rest of the logic
}
```

Comment: I literally just suggested it before you hahaha

Answer (score 0):

use unlink function to remove file from folder

```
if (auth()->user()->avatar) {
     $image_path = public_path('user-images/' . auth()->user()->avatar)
     unlink($image_path)
}
```